# Are there any custom font-awesome generators that I can use for the latest fonts?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, fonts

I am using font-awesome but only need a small subset of the icons. I have been using:

http://www.icnfnt.com/

However this seems to not be up to date.

I'm wondering why the font-awesome people don't have something similar. Has anyone found an up to date site that I could use like icnfnt.com but that works for latest font set.

Comment: Try [IcoMoon](http://icomoon.io/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, this website is for you : http://icomoon.io/app/

You can :

- add your svg icons
- select icons
- change tags
- add a lot of predefined icons pack
- ...